# JQuery question on mouseup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have list and the elements of the list can be selected (one at a time, or more with the help of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key) by mousedown event. I'd like to deselect the selected elements by mouseup on anywhere in document but these list elements.
I tried this but doesn't work:

```
$("body").delegate("body:not(.selected_li)", "mouseup", function(event) { .......
```

When I click anywhere on the document (but the selected `li`) the mouseup event dosen't take place.

Please, help me.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't delegate to the `body` from the body. `body` is the root element. See: http://api.jquery.com/delegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to bind your event listener to the body, and examine the clicked element to see if it is a `.selected_li`, *or one of its descendants*:

```
$('body').mouseup(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('.selected_li').length == 0) {
        // de-select
    }
});
```

The real trick here is using `.closest(".selected_li")` because it makes sure to include instances where you are over a child of a ".selected_li".

Using `.is(".selected_li")` won't work if your list happens to look anything like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li class="selected_li"><i>Item 2</i></li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

If you release your mouse button while over *Item 2*, `event.target` will be the `<i>` element, not the `<li>`, so `.is(".selected_li")` will return false.  So we must see if the event target or any of its ancestors are `".selected_li"` by searching using `.closest()` and checking to see if we got a match.

**Edit:**  Using `.delegate()` here is not a great idea.  That will bind an event handler to every descendant element of `<body>`, which is very redundant, since the event will always bubble up to `<body>` anyway and you only need to do it once.  However, it *is* possible, but you need to make sure to exclude enough - you'll need to exclude ".selected_li" and all of its descendants, and all of its anscestors:

```
$("body").delegate(":not(.selected_li, .selected_li *, :has(.selected_li))", "mouseup", function(e) {
    // de-select
});
```

But, this will lead to the event handler being called multiple times per click.  If you release the mouse button while over the following paragraph, you'll execute your event handler 5 times.  Once for each of `<em>`,`<p>`,`<div class="section">`,`<div id="content">`,`<div id="wrapper">`.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="section">
                <p><em>Here is a paragraph</em></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So, just bind once to body so that the event handler is called only once per click.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need..

```
$('body').mouseup(function(e){
   if ( !$(e.target).is('.selected_li') ) {
     // do the de-selection here..
   }
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/kw7v5/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can't delegate to the `body` from the `body`. `body` is your root element, so I think what you want is something like:

```
$("body").delegate("li:not(.selected_li)", "mouseup", function(event) {
  /* */
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/delegate

Comment: You will have to do a multi selector for the ul parent as well. Otherwise the mouseup event will appear to trigger on the li's when it triggers on the ul. Here is what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/kw7v5/1/

Comment: Revising answer to delegate only to `li` elements. On re-reading the question it seems like that's what matters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/kw7v5/

Just substitute your classes for the ul and li.

Comment: This will only work when the `<ul>` is a direct child of `<body>` and when the `<li>` has no child elements.  If you wrap the `<ul>` in a `<div>`, or throw a `<span>` inside the `<li>`, it fails.

Comment: Yeah I see that now. I think your answer is probably best. I was just trying to make it work with delegate, but I guess I never really stepped back to ask why delegate was being used in the first place.